# Which template to use for tabular data in TVML?

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'd like to render a bunch of table data in a TVML app similar to what iTunes music is already doing:

[image]

I looked through the templates in the TVML documentation site and didn't see anything that seemed relevant for rendering table data. Thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [compilationTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvml/compilationtemplate) and work on styling to achieve the style you want.

Also, if you have not downloaded the TVMLGuideCoreConcept or TVMLCatalog demo apps from Apple, must check it out. There are a lot of samples there that can help you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html